# How do you configure firefox to open an application without prompting the user?

Tags: firefox, download, mime-types

I've got a serverside app that send down a custom mime-type file "application/x-optibase".

Firefox prompt user user to save or open the file and if the user clicks open the correct application launches so I believe I have mimeType.rdf configured correctly

I've gone into about:config and set

browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile to application/x-optibase

and

browser.helpApps.alwaysAsk.force to false

According to the minimal documentation out there this should enable the application to automatically open when the user downloads the file but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a huge security risk to me.

Comment: This is for an internal application with a machine that is not  connected to internet. We're trying give the user a seemless experience and having to make them click through that screen everytime they run the process is quite annoying. Also they accidentaly clicked save instead of open as and then nothing happens which confuses them even more.

Comment: Peter: It doesn't matter. Firefox has no idea whether or not you're using this internally only; if it allowed this behavior it would have to allow it everywhere, and that would be a major security hole. Instruct your users on what to do, and don't try and open gaping holes for them; if you insist on doing so, they won't recognize when someone they *shouldn't* alow does the same. Otherwise, be ready to explain to someone much higher in your company why exactly you let something malicious invade your corporate network.

Answer (score 0):

Those preferences are no longer looked at as of Firefox 3.  You have to have the mimeTypes.rdf file setup correctly.  Specifically, for your mime type, you want to set NC:alwaysAsk to false.  See [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) for more details.

Comment: I've tries that as well. Here is a link to the portion of the mimeTypes.rdf file i'm using:

http://www.booleanconsulting.com/samples/stack_overflow_1.html

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why that doesn't work then.  You should probably file a bug.